# How to fix Google Script Error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined (line 59, file "Code")"?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this code that works fine. The code is supposed to copy and filter data from one spreadsheet to another using values in Column E. When I enter certain values like "Business 2", it runs fine. But if I enter other values like "Business 1", I get this error - "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined (line 59, file "Code")"

I have cleaned and trimmed the cell contents with =CLEAN(TRIM())

Here is the code

```
function copySheetValuesV2(){
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sourceName = source.getSheetName();
  var sValues = source.getDataRange().getValues();

  //var rawData = range.getValues()     // get value from spreadsheet 1
var data = []                       // Filtered Data will be stored in this array
for (var i = 0; i< sValues.length ; i++){
if(sValues[i][4] == "Business 1")            // Check to see if column E says "Business 1" if not skip it
{
data.push(sValues[i])
}
}

  var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById('idvalue');
  var shttoDelete = destination.getSheetByName('Copy of Dashboard');


  source.copyTo(destination);
  var destinationSheet = destination.getSheetByName('Copy of '+sourceName);
  destinationSheet.getRange(2,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);// overwrite all formulas that the copyTo preserved
  destinationSheet.getRange(data.length + 1,1,destinationSheet.getLastRow(),destinationSheet.getLastColumn()).clearContent();


}
```

I need help with finding why the script isn't reading certain values from the column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I typed the text "Business 1" in another cell. Then I copied it to replace the existing text in the column.

Comment: Thanks. This is a very helpful idea

Answer (score 2):

### `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` in your case means that the array `data` is empty

- Your code pushes `sValues` into `data` if `sValues[i][4] == "Business 1"`.
- If not, `data` stays empty and `data[0]` does not exist and thus has no length.
- You can avoid this error by verifying that `data` is not empty before running the rest of your code.
- The easiest way to do it would be with an `if` statement, e.g.

```
 if(data[0]){
    source.copyTo(destination);
    var destinationSheet = destination.getSheetByName('Copy of '+sourceName);   
    destinationSheet.getRange(2,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);// overwrite all formulas that the copyTo preserved    
    destinationSheet.getRange(data.length + 1,1,destinationSheet.getLastRow(),destinationSheet.getLastColumn()).clearContent();
  }
```